# How to reference a file when the path contain a shortcut

Tags: python, xml, windows, shortcut, win32com

In my program i am referencing to an xml file. But the location of the xml file is mapped through a shortcut,

C:\Test\Try\SPR\installation.xml

where the SPR is a shortcut. But when i access like this i get "Windows cant find' / File not found error.

if i access C:\Test\Try\SPR it works, but when a file name follows the shortcut i feel it is not able to de-reference the path.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Below is the code snippet i use to create the shortcut.

This is how create the short link from a script

```
import os
import win32com.client
def _create_link():
"""!
@brief      Function used to create the short link for the release and master folder

@param[in]  None

@return     None
"""
folder_path = os.path.join("C:\Test\Try", "SPR")  

path = os.path.join(folder_path, 'SPR.lnk')

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = "C:\Test\Try\SPR11"
shortcut.WindowStyle = 7 
shortcut.save()

_create_link()
```

Comment: Why use a shortcut and not the actual path?

Comment: "SPR.lnk" is just a regular file, which only has meaning to the shell API. We can't use it as a directory in a normal file path. We would have to read the target and compose the final path. For an actual directory, create a junction mountpoint (like a Unix bind mountpoint) or a directory symbolic link. These require a filesystem that supports reparse points, such as NTFS and ReFS. The system drive (C:) is required to be NTFS.